# Screen brightness in J2ME

Tags: api, java-me, brightness

Do you know of any means for changing the screen brightness in J2ME. That is using a vendor-specific API, like Samsung's, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is away to do it with the Nokia-specific API.

Comment: Some Sony Ericssons also supposedly support Nokia API - I haven't tried it myself, but I'll take a look into it, next time I'll try to make my old phone blink the keyboard or the like... http://mobilezoo.biz/sonyericsson.php#jp

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest is `Display.flashBacklight(int duration)`

http://www.microemu.org/microemu-midp/apidocs/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#flashBacklight%28int%29

Also see http://support.developer.motorola.com/cgi-bin/motodev.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=592&p_created=1170311265&p_topview=1

Comment: Thank you very much!

Unfortunately, this would only _flash_ the light, but would not control its brightness. I was looking for a way of making the screen more or less bright, which is pretty useful for the app I am writing. I've seen it's possible in Android though...