# Pointers as arguments of Win32 API in VB.NET?? (Adjust screen brightness in VB.NET)

Tags: pointers, c#-to-vb.net

I need to write something like [Adjust screen brightness using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013622/adjust-screen-brightness-using-c-sharp) in VB.NET but there is a pointer parameter in `SetDeviceGammaRamp(Int32 hdc, void* ramp)`. In VB6 there is `VarPtr()` to get around but it is no longer supported. Every code converter does not work with pointers in VB.NET and [C-style pointer in Visual Basic .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707520/c-style-pointer-in-visual-basic-net) states that there is no such thing as pointers in VB.NET so I wonder if there is a way to get around. Also, how should I declare the function?

BTW adjusting screen brightness is solved in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013622/adjust-screen-brightness-using-c-sharp), [Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691397/adjust-screen-brightness-in-mac-os-x-app), [J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564475/screen-brightness-in-j2me), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421356/adjust-screen-brightness-contrast-in-python) and even [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621490/android-2-2-adjusting-screen-brightness).

C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Brightness
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Class for manipulating the brightness of the screen
    /// </summary>
    public static class Brightness
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private unsafe static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(Int32 hdc, void* ramp);

        private static bool initialized = false;
        private static Int32 hdc;


        private static void InitializeClass()
        {
            if (initialized)
                return;

            //Get the hardware device context of the screen, we can do
            //this by getting the graphics object of null (IntPtr.Zero)
            //then getting the HDC and converting that to an Int32.
            hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();

            initialized = true;
        }

        public static unsafe bool SetBrightness(short brightness)
        {
            InitializeClass();

            if (brightness > 255)
                brightness = 255;

            if (brightness < 0)
                brightness = 0;

            short* gArray = stackalloc short[3 * 256];
            short* idx = gArray;

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                {
                    int arrayVal = i * (brightness + 128);

                    if (arrayVal > 65535)
                        arrayVal = 65535;

                    *idx = (short)arrayVal;
                    idx++;
                }
            }

            //For some reason, this always returns false?
            bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);

            //Memory allocated through stackalloc is automatically free'd
            //by the CLR.

            return retVal;

        }
    }
}
```

Why code converters don't work with pointers in VB.NET (There is no class called `Pointer(Of T)`):

```vb
<DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc As Int32, ramp As Pointer(Of System.Void)) As Boolean
End Function

Dim gArray As Pointer(Of Short) = stackalloc
Dim idx As Pointer(Of Short) = gArray
```

Don't think this is needed as `hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32()` does it.

```vb
<DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc As IntPtr, lpRamp As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

Comment: `Pointer(Of System.Void)` is `IntPtr`.

Comment: Which you don't even need to know, because you simply declare an array of `3 * 256` `short`s and declare the function as `byval hdc As intptr, <MarshalAs(LPArray), In()> ramp As short()`.

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetDeviceGammaRamp.html

Comment: @GSerg Wait, what?? Isn't `IntPtr` `Pointer(Of Integer)`??

Comment: And where did my first comment go?

Comment: `IntPtr` is `Pointer(Of Anything)` @Happypig375. Your comment [was flagged and deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/147640) because [we hate fun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/147640).